# How to make canvas element exact size of window?

Tags: ios, css, html, web-applications, canvas

I'd like to create canvas element to take all space of window, with no scrolling. I do the follow:

1. Reset margins and paddings
2. Take size of window
3. Remove all children of body
4. Create canvas, set canvas size to window size
5. Add canvas to body

It works, but I taken a few extra pixels at the bottom of page, and browser scrolls to up and down to show these pixels. I tested it on iPad and Android (Galaxy Nexus) - the same effect, so it is like not a bag, but misunderstanding feature.

Do you have ideas what are these pixels and how to remove them?

The code:

```
<!DOCTYPE html> 
<html> 
<head> 
  <meta charset="UTF-8" />
  <title>My Page</title> 
  <meta name="apple-mobile-web-app-capable" content="yes" />
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width,initial-scale=1,user-scalable=no" />
  <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="http://meyerweb.com/eric/tools/css/reset/reset.css" />
  <script type="text/javascript" src="http://ajax.aspnetcdn.com/ajax/jQuery/jquery-1.8.3.min.js"></script>
  <script type="text/javascript">
    $(function() {
      initApp();
    });

    function initApp() {
      windowWidth = $(window).width();
      windowHeight = $(window).height();

      canvas = document.createElement('canvas');
      canvas.width = windowWidth;
      canvas.height = windowHeight;
      context = canvas.getContext("2d");

      var body = document.getElementById("bo");
      while (body.firstChild) {
        body.removeChild(body.firstChild);
      }
      body.appendChild(canvas);

      // write something for test
      context.fillStyle = "#00ff00";
      context.fillRect(0, 0, windowWidth, windowHeight);
      context.fillStyle = "#ff0000";
      context.fillRect(0, 0, 200, 200);
      context.fillStyle = "#000000";
      context.font = '20px _sans';
      context.textBaseline = 'top';
      context.fillText ("Canvas " + windowWidth + "x" + windowHeight + "!", 0, 0);
    }

  </script>
</head> 
<body id="bo">
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 1):

If you're just looking to get rid of the scrollbars and you aren't worried about missing those extra couple of pixels, just add the CSS style `overflow: hidden` to the body element. Also try adding `display: block` to the canvas element.